# Will travellers be able to get full internet access in Turkey during the current (July 2013) protests/riots?

Tags: turkey, internet, event-based-effects

With the [current widespread riots in Turkey](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-22776946), the police reaction, the government's intervention and the worldwide observation, there've been reports of threats to have the internet restricted, as has happened in nearby countries in recent years.

For travellers currently in Turkey, what, if any of the internet is not presently available or is being actively censored from within Turkey?

Comment: As it currently stands, your question is too localized.

Comment: @Dirty-flow we had very similar questions about Egypt during the events there.

Comment: @Dirty-flow Fortunately unrests tend to be localized last 2 world wide ones weren't particularly pleasant...

Comment: @Karlson unrests are actually one of the main reasons most of us now have so many rights. They have nothing to do with wars. But I do agree that this seems a little bit too localized, maybe it could be made more general (internet censorship in Turkey) with a special focus on actual events - like the good answer by Karlson suggest

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a past event.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [generally censorship in Turkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censorship_in_Turkey) related to various topics like Ataturk, Islam, etc.

Apparently there have been additional censorship and limiting of access to social networks as Twitter and Facebook but people have gotten around that too according [Net Security](http://www.net-security.org/secworld.php?id=15005) and [Guardian](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2013/jun/04/turkish-protestors-encryption-software-evade-censors).

Answer (score 3):

The Internet access is currently available. The deputy prime minister told that as the government they have the power to cut the access to social media such as Twitter and Facebook, but they will not do it since they are democratic :) So no worries. As I said, you can have the Internet connection via 3G, wi-fi networks, or cable without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

Turkey has had censorship for a while due to it's penal codes, which results in strange bans (things like Youtube going down, Google apps being affected by bans of individual google sites etc.) that are sometimes overturned.

If you want to surf generally without restriction you could do worse than have a look at [Lahana](http://lahana.dreamcats.org/). It was specifically designed for general censorship free surfing. [Tor](http://www.torproject.org/) is another option if anonymity or privacy is particularly important.

Comment: "Lahana.Dreamcats.org" has an invalid SSL certificate.  Suspicious.  The FAQ on the parent domain shows a snobby geek attitude.  One would think such a group would take pride in properly registering their certificate.