# Is pre-revolutionary artwork uncensored in Iranian museums?

Tags: culture, museums, iran, nudism

I came across a tweet today saying

> It isn't only in Rome Museum that nude statues threaten Islam. Tehran's Iran Bastan Museum has nude statue of [Anahita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anahita), pre-Islamic goddess.

Is artwork pre-dating the Iranian revolution generally uncensored in Iranian museums?

If the artworks are censored, are they just stored away from public view (something which can be reversed in the future - I'm flexible about when I visit Iran), or are they sold and/or destroyed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about archive management.

Comment: Not an authoritative source but "The Tehran Museum of Contemporary Art’s building and collection was developed by the West infatuated Shah. There have been few acquisitions since the Islamic Revolution, and according to guidebooks the collection is seldom on display" - http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/trip-reports/1357398-youre-driving-mongolia-charity-mongol-rally-2012-a-2.html

Comment: @Flimzy err, should it be about archive management? It's definitely about travel because it's about the contents of country's museums, which are a type of visitor attraction.

Comment: @user568458: It's about the the political opression laws of Iran, and about where Iran stores censored art. The first is border-line travel related, but still feels more about political oppression than travel, IMO. The second is obviously NOT travel related.

Comment: @Flimzy are we reading the same question? "Is artwork pre-dating the Iranian revolution generally uncensored in Iranian museums?". How is that not asking what's displayed in Iranian museums? That's the core question, and there's nothing wrong with also asking for a little context.

Comment: @user568458: Yup, we're reading the same question. You're just ignoring my comments. But that's fine. We have a difference of opinion. This is allowed. I have but one vote.

Comment: @Flimzy if you know for a fact that there is a "political repression law" against nude or pre-Islamic antiquities, that's *the answer to the question*, not a reason to close it. If you don't, then it's pure speculation. Maybe it's down to the discretion of each museum curator - in which case someone who has traveled in Iran can give an interesting and useful answer about which museums display what antiquities. You're trying to prevent such an answer from being written (thereby trying to prevent me and others from reading it).

Comment: @user568458: The question is expressly about censorship, which is a form of political oppression. No speculation involved. At all.

Comment: @user568458: And all I'm "trying to prevent" is the degradation of this site by cluttering with off-topic posts.

Comment: @Flimzy please point me to the rule that says normal travel questions like "Can I see X type of artifact in museums in Y country" become suddenly off-topic when censorship is a likely factor. There are plenty of questions on this site about ways in which censorship can affect travelers - [here's one example](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17898/will-travellers-be-able-to-get-full-internet-access-in-turkey-during-the-current)

Comment: The general rule is that questions that relate equally to locals as to visitors are off topic. There is a lot of grey area. This is where we use our judgment. In my judgment, this question falls too far on the "not travel related" side. Your judgement may be different, and that's fine. I have no desire to convince you. I have no ax to grind. I'm done with this conversation.

Comment: @Flimzy I've updated the question to add a rationale.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a difference between pre-islamic and pre-revolutionary. As a rule of thumb, pre-islamic art is uncensored, pre-revolutionary (but islamic) is censored, often heavily.

(I noticed part of your question I didn't see before, perhaps because you updated it.) During the early years of the revolution, there was a lot of religious zeal that saw some irreversible changes on a lot of fronts. Based on my general knowledge of Iran (I was born there, left when I was young, still have quite a bit of family there), I'd say that some art disappeared (but more likely into someone's cabinet than on top of the rubbish bin), but that quite a bit of it is tucked away for better times. Though, the longer those better times take to occur, the less likely these pieces will ever see the light of day.

Comment: Interesting, can you give any examples?

Comment: @user568458 It's hard to give examples of things that are not available. It's not that easy to find pre-revolutionary art in Iranian museums, as a lot ware removed during the early years of the revolution.

Comment: @MastaBaba haha, true, I was thinking more what *kind* of art it is that is missing from the museums. Do you mean like the Western-style fashion and pop-art that was getting quite big in Iran in the 60s and 70s? And any examples of museums showcasing pre-Islamic antiquities?

Comment: @user568458 Yeah, that sums it up quite well. That said, if you're interested, this book is very much worth a gander: http://amzn.to/1PDiflf

Comment: Yes, I updated it a bit. I didn't want to make my logic too explicit because I didn't want to be needlessly rude, but because the question was threatened with closure, I decided to be more explicit.